# What style assembly is this (intel, att...etc?) and how can I produce it?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm trying to produce assembly code like this (so that it works with nasm)

```
;hello.asm
[SECTION .text]

global _start


_start:

    jmp short ender

    starter:

    xor eax, eax    ;clean up the registers
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor edx, edx
    xor ecx, ecx

    mov al, 4       ;syscall write
    mov bl, 1       ;stdout is 1
    pop ecx         ;get the address of the string from the stack
    mov dl, 5       ;length of the string
    int 0x80

    xor eax, eax
    mov al, 1       ;exit the shellcode
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 0x80

    ender:
    call starter    ;put the address of the string on the stack
    db 'hello'
```

First off, what assembly style is this and second, how can I produce it from a C file using a command similar to `gcc -S code.c -o code.S -masm=intel`

Comment: `-masm=intel` is exactly what produces this style (Intel syntax, as opposed to the default AT&T syntax). But that governs only the actual instructions. Things like `[SECTION]` are NASM-specific, and GCC always generates GAS-specific ones.

Comment: Then how come when I run the above command with (-masm=intel) and then I try to run the command `nasm -f elf code.S` I get a whole bunch of errors?

Comment: Because nasm is not gas.  The directives are wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you explain a little more on what you mean?

Comment: @Nosrettap - One part of the style is that it looks like **hand written** assembly. Could that be part of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Intel style.

What's wrong with the commandline you wrote in the question?

Comment: It's just that if I use that command, and then I try to use the command `nasm -f elf code.S` I get a whole bunch of errors